# AWS IoT Rule - HTTP Destinations Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, sigv4

I have an IoT project where device sends telemetry data to AWS IoT Core. And I used **AWS IoT Core Rules** to read data from topic and send it to my own **webservice** deployed in some other place. When I am try to add authentication in HTTP Rule, it is showing **SigV4** based authentication. What is that and how to use it ? Do I need to any code changes in my **webservice** ?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I cam to know, that sig4 is used to call AWS services, not other webhooks. So I am planning to invoke, Lambda and push the data